# Dirichlet problem on a wire: a co-dimension 2 boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, potential-theory, electromagnetism

A wire may be thought of as a smooth compact curve $C \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with boundary two endpoints. Suppose we are given a smooth $\phi: C \to \mathbb{R}$ (a potential on the wire), then can $\phi$ be uniquely extended to $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$\triangle \phi = 0 \quad \text{on } \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus C $$ and $\phi = o(1)$ at $\infty$ ?

Is there an explicit solution for interesting curves, such as a circular arc with potentials (somehow) increasing from one endpoint to the next?

This would model the field outside a wire.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a unique answer to this question.

Consider for example a circle $C$ on  the xy plane and two spheres $S_1$ and $S_2$ kept at constant potential $V_0$ that cross each other sharing as their common boundary the circle C. It is obvious that the circle is kept at the same constant potential in both cases, but the electric fields produced by these two configurations are different if $V_0\neq V(r=\infty)$, since the two spheres are necessarily centered at different points in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: The potential in this example is invalid because it violates the Laplace equation at points on the sphere thay are not on the circle. The potential is not differentiable there, the electric field is discontinuous.

Comment: Ok I see where this is going .Let's say in 2-D , if you solve the Laplace equation at a codimension two boundary, which is a point, you get an infinity of solutions corresponding to that boundary condition . By the way, this is the problem to which a 3-D problem is reduced: consider $C$ an infinite linear wire at constant potential, in which case by symmetry we can reduce the problem to a two dimensional one with a boundary condition at a single point. This is a counterexample for a non compact curve, and I'm curious about your motivation to think that this problem has a unique solution.

Comment: If we were to model a wire as a surface (a tube) rather than a curve, this statement is true (dirichlet boundary problem on the exterior of curve... note the decay condition at infinity gives uniqueness from maximal principle) hence the motivation. I think your idea to look at a point $P$ in 2D is a good starting point. This satisfies uniqueness also by maximal principle (note the vanishing at infinity). I am now starting to doubt the existence however. because if you specify boundary condition $\phi(P) = 1$ then we are looking for a bounded harmonic non-constant function.

Comment: Yea now that I understand your requirements better, it seems that you are asking a little bit too much, boundedness at every point including infinity. This is an even stronger requirement than the function being entire in 2-D. Even in 3-D in spherical coordinates, even before imposing the boundary condition, boundedness everywhere, including infinity permits only trivial solutions. I do not know if the situation changes in higher dimensions, in terms of the spherical coordinates, but maybe it is worth investigating.